# Forcing negative input depending on type

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I have a simple spreadsheet with three columns:

A   **Category** (Data validation drop down list allowing only "Asset" or "Debt")
B   **Description** (free form; e.g. Home (Asset), Mortgage (Debt)
C   **Amount** (I want to force only positive numbers if Column A says "Asset" and only negative numbers if Column A says "Debt")

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Could you use the ABS (absolute value) function? Abs(x) is *always* positive, even if x is negative. -Abs(x) is always negative..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom data validation for that:

go to data - data validation, it'll open "data validation" form, here:

- allow: Custom
- Formula:
  `=OR(AND(A2="Asset",C2>=0),AND(A2="Debt",C2<=0))`

It'll allow only positive (or 0) values for "asset" and negative (or 0) for "Debt". Every other cases (including other value in column A, or non-numeric in column C you'll get an error).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

See [this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/599614-limiting-cell-negative-values-only.html) 
Possible answer from the link above:

> Select the range of cells in question
>   Goto the Data tab
>   In the Data Tools group select Data Validation
>   Allow: Decimal
>   Data: Less than or equal to 
>   Maximum: 0
>   OK out

EDIT: You also can use an IF condition which will perform negative Abs() [as suggested by @DrMoishe Pippik] on the values if drop down option chosen is "debt".